# Unable to open .cod file with double click

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I recently made a format to the computer. I installed the JDK for blackberry and configured the signing tools.

When I double click on a **.cod** file, it tells me to choose the program to open with. What program to choose to open .cod file to make the sign directly?

Please help with this I tried all the java files and didn't succeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following steps.

1. Created a bat file in `JDE/bin` folder with the command inside:

   java -jar SignatureTool.jar %1
2. Opened a .cod file properties and clicked on "Change" button in "Opens with..."
3. Selected this .bat file (created on step 1).

It works. Just make sure, that you create .bat file in the folder where SignatureTool.jar is located.

Comment: I did what you told and it works if I place the .cod file inside the folder where Signature tool is located. But when I run a .cod file not located in this folder it gives me an error : Unable to access SignatureTool.jar. What is the problem?

Comment: Forgot to mention: add JDE/bin folder to the system PATH variable. Or specify the full path to SignatureTool.jar in your bat file.

Answer (score 0):

The tool to sign is `SignatureTool.jar`. It is usually placed in the `bin` directory of the JDE folder (`C:\Program files\Research in Motion\Blackberry JDE X.x.x\bin`).

You can launch it from command line:

```
SignatureTool.jar -c -p <password> somefile.cod
SignatureTool.jar -c -p <password> -r somedirectory
```

So you can make a small `.bat` file to launch it from command line. What I don't know is if it is possible to associate a certain file extension to a .bat file in windows.

Comment: I used to run the cod file by double clicking on it. Now it is not working. I know what you told me but I prefer to run it by double clicking on it. Any idea of that?